# Как отловить данные пользователя при авторизации через соц.сети?

Tags: python, django, oauth

Я добавил на свой сайт авторизацию через соц сети.
Как я могу узнать, что пользователь использовал именно такую авторизацию?
В процессе авторизации пользователя через соц сети мне надо изменить значение verified в таблице базы данных, а так же добавить его фотографию в эту таблицу.

Примечание: Я не переписывал стандартную модель пользователя, а расширил её путем создания ForeignKey в таблицу Profile. В этой таблице хранится информации о пользователе (номер телефона, пол, и т.д), и именно поэтому мне надо отловить информацию и явно прописать где она должна быть записана.
Примечание2: Для авторизации через соц.сети я использовал social-auth-app-django